# Receive bluetooth serial data to android in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth

I'd like to use Unity for develope android game with my bluetooth serial data. I can write angle data to PC but i need to show in android app but i dont know how make a connection between bluetooth and android app using Unity.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class checker : MonoBehaviour {

    public static SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM8", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    public string message, message1;
    public string message2;



    void Start() {

        OpenConnection();   


    }

    void Update() { 

        message2 = sp.ReadLine(); 

    } 

    void OnGUI()    {

        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 180, 100, 220), "Sensor1: " + message2);

    }


    public void OpenConnection() {
        if (sp != null) 
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen) 
            {
                sp.Close();
                message = "Closing port, because it was already open!";
            }
            else 
            {
                sp.Open(); 
                sp.ReadTimeout = 1000;  
                message = "Port Opened!";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                print("Port is already open");
            }
            else 
            {
                print("Port == null");
            }
        }
    }




    void OnApplicationQuit() {
        sp.Close();
    }



}
```